# Django: How to render HTML template based on tuple choice

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have created a model, views and templates like so:

**MODEL**

```
project_choices = (
    ('Speaker', (
        ('help', 'Freedom'),
    )),
    ('Money', (
        ('invest', 'Investment'),
    )
    ),
    (
        'Children', (
            ('mc', 'Mother & Child'),
        )
    ),
)


class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = CKEditor5Field('Text', null=True)
    limitation = models.CharField(
        null=True, max_length=50, choices=project_choices)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Now the **VIEW**

```
def view_portfolio(request):
    blog= Blog.objects.all()
    template = 'blog/blog.html'
    context = {'blog': blog}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

then the **hmtl template**

```
        {% for blog in blog%}
            {% if blog.limitation['**help**'] %}**//I have also tried {% if portfolio.limitation == project_choices['AI']%}**
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
              <div class="portfolio-wrap">
                <img src="{{blog.featured}}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                <div class="blog-info">
                  <h4>{{blog.title}}</h4>
                  <p></p>
                  <div class="portfolio-links">
                    <a href="{{blog.featured}}" data-gall="blogGallery" class="venobox" title="{{blog.title}}"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                    <a href="blog-details.html" title="More Details"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}  
      {%endfor%}
```

My goal is to show blogs based on ONLY **help** as the chosen choice please how can I achieve this?
I am using django3

Comment: How come you have limitation = models.BooleanField  and adding Choises and max_length it must be charfield

Comment: Thanks a lot @PavanKumarTS I have corrected the observed issue, however when loading the template I still get the similar error : Could not parse the remainder: '['AI']' from 'portfolio.limitation['AI']' your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you see the value you are storing in limitation is char so you dont need to use like ['AI'] . You can just user as follows {% if blog.limitation == 'help' %}

Comment: Oh thank you very much @PavanKumarTS I really appreciate sir.